# What bike have I bought?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Can anybody help me identify this bike? It's a Claud Butler with Reynolds 531 steel - that's all I know. [image]

Comment: It would be easier if you took some close-ups of various features: the Reynolds 531 sticker (it will show if the frame tubes are plain gauge or butted), the dropouts, the lugs, the serial number, and so forth. <a href="http://homepage.ntlworld.com/nkilgariff/ClaudButler.htm">Here's a reference which may be of interest</a>.

Comment: Here's a [working link](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/nkilgariff/ClaudButler.htm) to the reference in the previous comment.

Comment: It's a fairly standard road bike from the mid 80s.  Based on the [Wikipedia article for Claud Butler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claud_Butler), it could have been manufactured by Holdsworth or Falcon.

Comment: The bike on http://i141.photobucket.com/albums/r77/hilarystone/Claud-Butler-Regent-lfgss_zps5a21804c.jpg from http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=301820 has the same frame, the year seems to be about 1991.

Comment: The seat tube looks a bit odd.  Does it extend all the way to the top there, or is that a seat post?

Comment: @Klaster_1 -- Note that the OP's bike has a short cage and relatively close front sprockets.  The one you link has a long cage and what would count as a granny (though still only two rings, close as I can tell).  Also, the OP's doesn't appear to have fender lugs on the front dropout, and it has tighter spacing between rear wheel and seat tube.  Conclusion:  The OP's is more of a road racer, yours a light touring bike.

Comment: You sir, have bought a great bike :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard English manufactured sport bike probably from the mid-60's.

It used freewheel type hubs and from what I can see you appear to have modified the rear wheel with a seven speed freewheel. The original rear triangle spacing was probably 125 mm and the seven speed uses a 127 mm spacing. Usually someone would re-space the rear triangle and put a spacer on the right side of the axle and normally they would not re-center the rim. This would cause the wheel to be slightly off-center in the stays. It usually had no deleterious effect.12speed

Comment: Where do you get "mid-60's"?  The downtube shifters and cotterless crank are clearly indicative of a couple of decades later.

Comment: Where were shifters before they were on the down tube? I'm pretty sure my road bike in the '60s had down tube shifters and my dad's Schwann Varsity was very modern with its stem shifters. From what I've read Stronglight invented cotterless cranks in the '30s.

Comment: Single water bottle braze-one became common in the early eighties.  Double ones (like this bike) in the mid eighties.  Of course, they could have been added later.